# Adjusting VoronoiMesh size

Tags: plotting, mesh

How it is possible to extend VoronoiMesh to the whole ListPlot in the following example?

```
pts = {{-3, -4}, {-2, 1}, {3, -2}};
Show[
 ListPlot[2 pts, 
  PlotRange -> Automatic,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False],
ListPlot[
 pts, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 PlotMarkers -> {"\[Cross]", 36},
 PlotStyle -> Red
],

HighlightMesh[
 VoronoiMesh[pts],
 {Style[2, Transparent], Style[1, Thin, Red], Labeled[2, "Index"]}]
]
```

[image]

Instead I would like to get something like this

[image]

without indicating VoronoiMesh range explicitly, like proposed in comments

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "extending the Voronoi mesh"? The code you show does not generate the plot you included. Can you explain the relationship between the two?

Comment: Use `VoronoiMesh[pts, {{-6, 6}, {-8, 2}}]` instead of just `VoronoiMesh[pts]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack, but it seems to do what you are asking by creating a new mesh object from the old one.

```
pts = {{-3, -4}, {-2, 1}, {3, -2}};
vm = VoronoiMesh@pts;
oldcoords = MinMax /@ Transpose[MeshCoordinates@vm] // Flatten;
plot1 = ListPlot[2 pts,
   PlotRange -> Automatic,
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> False];
newcoords = plot1 // Charting`get2DPlotRange // Flatten;
plot2 = ListPlot[pts,
   PlotRange -> Automatic,
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> False,
   PlotMarkers -> {"\[Cross]", 36},
   PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[
 plot1,
 plot2,
 HighlightMesh[ 
  MeshRegion[(MeshCoordinates@vm) /. Thread[oldcoords -> newcoords], 
   MeshCells[vm, 2]],
  {Style[2, Transparent], Style[1, Thin, Red], Labeled[2, "Index"]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Does not work "Objects of unequal length in \
{MinMax[{-0.357143,-4.5,2.15,0.75,-4.5,-4.5,4.5,4.5}],MinMax[{-1.\
92857,-1.1,2.25,-5.25,-5.25,2.25,-5.25,2.25}]}->{-6.24,6.24,-8.5,2.5} \
cannot be combined."

Comment: What version are you using?  Does it work if you replace `MinMax` with `{Min@#, Max@#} &`?

Comment: I use version 10.0.2.0

Comment: Yes with {Min@#, Max@#} & it works! thank you